# I2C Research Questions

Tags: i2c, serial

I have some questions regarding the I2C protocol. Is it possible to use multiplexing/demultiplexing to combine the sda and scl lines into a single one? Is it possible to use multiplexing/demultiplexing to create an extended I2C protocol where two masters can speak on the same bus at the same time to two different slaves?

Comment: No, because slaves have no control over the clock. The clock only comes from the master.

Comment: @DKNguyen Except for clock stretching, but that still doesn't get you what Andrealphus wants.

Comment: @Hearth Yeah. Slave can suppress a clock but can't drive a clock so a collision between slave data and master clock would occur.

Comment: But isn't there a way to connect, for example, two master's SDAs to a 2 to 1 multiplexer (one input for each master) that switches between the two masters at some clock rate. I was thinking this might not be possible due to the pull up resistors, etc.

Comment: @Andrealphus But that's not what you described in the your original post. In your original post you asked to combine the SDA and SCL lines into a single line. And this second thing you are now bringing up is not necessary: "*two master's SDAs to a 2 to 1 multiplexer (one input for each master) that switches between the two masters at some clock rate.*" because I2C is already a multimaster bus.

Comment: It is the second question I Had.

Comment: If it's the second question then you just hook everything up to the same I2C bus. I2C supports multimaster bus. But you do need to take care pull-ups are not duplicated. If multiple devices on the line, whether slave or master, are bringing along their own pull-ups which are each sized to be the only pull-up on the line then you need to do something about that.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But when one master speaks, all other masters are not able to transmit data.

Comment: @Andrealphus Correct. That will be the case if you use multimaster I2C.

Comment: I suggest you find another alternative. It's going to be a buttload of work to make an I2C cross switch since the cross switch will need to be able to arbitrate. It would basically be its own multi-channel I2C device that is capable of simultaneously passing I2C messages (which are bidirectional of course which complicates things) but also intercepting and middle-manning messages so that if a master tries to talk to a slave that is unavailable, it can block the message from getting to the slave while sending something back to the master to notify that the slave is busy and terminate the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139365/discussion-between-andrealphus-and-dknguyen).

Comment: I2C is a multi-slave / multi-master 2-wire protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert I2C transactions to any other protocol that runs on 1 wire, such as UART, and convert them back to I2C transations. So if you only ask if it is possible in any way, yes, but it depends what you mean by multiplexing, so it might be a no.

I2C won't allow two masters to communicate on a single bus simultaneously, as only one transaction may be going on the I2C bus at any given time, so if you only ask if it is possible, no it isn't.